# Compare All Strings in a List - C#

Tags: c#, string, list, compare

I have `List<String> clr9`, which has a known `Count` of nine.

What I want to know is how to shorthand something that goes on later in the code.

```
else if(clr9[0].Equals(clr9[1]) && clr9[0].Equals(clr9[2]) && clr9[0].Equals(clr9[3]))
```

I've already tried this:

```
else if(clr9[0].Equals(clr9[1].Equals(clr9[2].Equals(clr9[3]))))
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any way I can avoid the ampersands?
*Basically just asking if there's a way to find out if all 4 strings are the same without cluttering up that if statement.*

Comment: I might need to add that the numbers next to the clrs dictate their capacity. so clr9 would have 9 items in it. I'm only checking if the first 4 are the same. Not the entire list.

Comment: `crlX.Skip(1).Take(3).All(str => str == clrX[0])`

Comment: @Chamkey you don't need to check the capacity, distincting will work for any length of list

Answer (score 1):

You could distinct the list to remove duplicates and check the length.

e.g.

`clr9.Distinct().Count() == 1`

or, if you want it to be case insensitive

`clr9.Distinct(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).Count() == 1`

Answer (score 1):

Distinct will work, but I think testing equality directly is more expressive of intent:

```
if(clr9.Skip(1).All(c => c.Equals(clr9[0])))
```

Comment: I upvoted as I think this is the best solution so far, but I would use `c == clr9[0]` instead.

Comment: For String I tend to use `Equals(String)`.  It's more verbose, in this case perhaps more cluttered than the equality operator.  But for `String` I prefer the syntactical affinity with `Equals(String, StringComparison)` to the prettier `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're only checking all the strings inside a single list like for example `clr9`. What you can do is use LINQ `Distinct`:

```
if (clr9.Distinct().Skip(1).Any())
{
  //Do something
}
```

T

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this situation often enough that I've written a simple extension method for it.

```
public static bool In<T>(this T val, params T[] options)
{
    return options.Contains(val);
}
```

And then to use it in your code statement

```
else if (clr9[0].In(clr9.Skip(1).ToArray()))
```

Edit based on comment by OP, this works just as well:

```
else if (clr9[0].In(clr9[1], clr9[2], clr9[3]))
```

Or

```
else if (clr9[0].In(clr9.Skip(1).Take(3).ToArray())
```

Comment: `object`?!?!?! Why not make the method generic?